# I have parent child relationship in two column excel sheet want a excel formula to derive all child and subchild against each row in third column

Tags: tree, branch, parent-child, topology, multilevel-analysis

I have parent child relationship in two column excel sheet want a excel formula to derive all child and sub-child against each row in third column

Input is in excel columns

column1 columnn2
Child   Parent
B   A
C   B
D   C
E   C
F   E
G   A
T   G
YU  D

Output will be in third column
column 1 Column2 Column3

Child   Parent  All childs
B   A   B,C,D,E,F,G,T,YU
C   B   C,D,E,F,YU
D   C   D,E,F,YU
E   C   D,E,F,YU
F   E   F
G   A   B,C,D,E,F,G,T,YU
T   G   T
YU  D   YU

Comment: Please post the input and output in the question in place of the images

Comment: Input is in excel columns

column1 columnn2
Child Parent
B A
C B
D C
E C
F E
G A
T G
YU D


Output will be in third column
column 1 Column2 Column3

Child Parent All childs
B A B,C,D,E,F,G,T,YU
C B C,D,E,F,YU
D C D,E,F,YU
E C D,E,F,YU
F E F
G A B,C,D,E,F,G,T,YU
T G T
YU D YU